# Creating a JFrame from another JFrames constructor

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 3 objects that extend `JFrame` let's call them `FrameA` `FrameB` `FrameC`.

`FrameA` is my main application window. From `FrameA`'s constructor if the application is not registered I create `FrameB` and `FrameC`. They are just popup's that indicate trial period.

2 times out of 10 application freezes and never shows the B anc C frame and frame A becomes unresponsive.

I was wondering if there is a side effect of creating frames in this fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not letting FrameA finish it's construction process, you're interrupting it and then in the same thread displaying those two other frames.

I would suggest to change your strategy and use a factory method and probably in conjunction with SwingUtilities.invokeLater method.

Let say you have something like:

```
 public static void main( String [] args ) {
      JFrame a = new FrameA(); // Has both display logic and trial "pop up" logic
 }
```

Change it for:

```
 public static void main( String [] args ) {
      JKFrame a = FrameA.createFrame(); // the same but splited like the following code 
 }


 class FrameA extends JFrame {
      // new method
      public static JFrame createFrame() {
            return new FrameA();  

      }
 }
```

Nothing changed you just added the factory method, later you can:

```
         public static JFrame createFrame() {
            if( thatSpecialLogicSaysItIsTrialAndShouldPopUp() ) {
                  JFrame b = new FrameB();
                  b.setVisible( true );
                  JFrame c = new FrameC();
                  c.setVisible( true );
                  return new FrameA();

           } else {
            return new FrameA();
           }  

      }
```

What you will be  doing in the second code is separate the logic from the class constructor and put it in the factory method. That way if *thatSpecialLogicSaysItIsTrialAndShouldPopUp* returns true, you display B and C

You can also as described use a JDialog there, but pretty much the problems will be gone when you separate the responsabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe sounds like something's locking up the event thread - this may or may not have anything to do with how you're launching the frames - you'll want to run in a debugger and when it starts exhibiting the symptoms check on the state of the event thread.

(Though I would agree with everyone else in the thread that you should pull the frame launching logic to some other place - however - there's nothing "unsafe" about calling frame constructors from another frame constructor - they're no different from any other constructor.  It may be bad design - but it shouldn't lock up the event thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to use a JDialog.  There made to do this exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about your logic. Creation of new frames in constructor of another frame sounds strange. If you doing it in the constructor - that means that first frame is not shown yet. Why don't you show you frame B and C outside of frame A constructor - logically it seems to be the same. But then depending on your conditions you can create Frame A and set it visible.